# How can I use `IN` with a list of strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I am trying to replace semicolon-separated strings(;) with comma-separated strings(,) in the where condition and have tried this in the where clause but I do not work. Can anyone help me with the solution?

```sql
s.securitydepartment in (REPLACE('Leverkusen;Waterford',';',','))
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Why use `IN` when you're only passing a scalar value? `s.securitydepartment IN ('Leverkusen,Waterford')` and `s.securitydepartment = 'Leverkusen,Waterford'` are synonyms.

Comment: I think you want to convert the string "leverkusen;waterford" into a table containing two distinct entries ("leverkusen" and "waterford").
You can achieve this with STRING_SPLIT: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: `IN` works on the items passed to it, not their contents. `'3,5'` is still a single string item.

Comment: All supported SQL Server versions (ie 2016 and later) have `STRING_SPLIT`. You can use it to split the string and join with the results. You won't get the performance benefits of `IN` though. The only way to do that is to generate and execute a dynamic SQL query. Client-side ORMs like Entity Framework and Dapper can generate such `IN` clauses

Comment: @Vendec yes I want from (leverkusen;waterford) to (Leverkusen,Waterford)

Comment: @Sourav no, you want to use `IN` with a CSV. You can't. That's it. You'll have to split that string instead

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, what you probably want is something like this:

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM {Your Table} YT
     JOIN STRING_SPLIT('Leverkusen;Waterford',';') SS ON YT.securitydepartment = SS.[Value]
WHERE ...
```

Of course, however, as `'Leverkusen;Waterford'` is a literal though, why not just fix the query and do:

```sql
s.securitydepartment IN ('Leverkusen','Waterford')
```

Answer (score 2):

`In` is a operator that works on a *set*, not a string.

You need to provide a set of values, a string is not "parsed" in any way or treated as a comma-separated list.

You can use `string_split` to return a set of values, for example

```
and s.securityDepartment in (select value from string_split('value1;value2;value3',';'))
```